# Stick an element to a certain position

Tags: html, css

I have a product card that display the ratings and mention "free shipping" if it is the case. If a product has no ratings but free shipping, the text is not aligned with other product card. How do I make all free shipping text to be aligned at the same position on the card?

I don't know which position attribute to use or if I need to wrap my text to fix his position.

```
<div class="body-info">
    ...
    <div class="product-rating">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty-half"></i>
        <span>4.5/5</span>
    </div>
    <a href="free-shipping">free shipping available</a>
</div>
```

Which position attributes should I use?

Thank you for helping me!

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of my problem

I want to add that if my product has no ratings, it doesn't display the "product-rating div".

[image]

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: you should be use position:absolute, but I'm not clear on what your requirement is

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit [ask] - hint: post effort

Comment: put screenshots with what you get and what you expected.

Comment: My idea is to say "if no ratings, free-shipping get margin-top for x%" but I suppose that there is an other way.

Comment: Is it a possible solution to just give the `.product-rating` a fixed height?

Comment: I see a bigger bottle on the right, is that the problem?

Comment: No because the img keep the same size

Comment: You can use flexbox for that and align everything to the bottom (flex-end). Or you can simply put a fixed height to the ratings div, and render it even if it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` for this. Add `flex: display` to the "body-info" and a `flex-grow: 1` to the text div, so the height will grow filling the empty space of the ratings div, pushing the shipping link to the bottom of the card.

Example: https://codepen.io/giumagnani/pen/ROGEow

```css
.body-info {
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.img {
  height: 150px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.text {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

EDIT: In this case I think it should be better to give fixed heights to your elements and always render them to keep the equal white spaces. You can also show a placeholder message like "There are no ratings yet".

Comment: I tried your code and it's great thank you but when the product card only display the ratings, the element is not aligned https://ibb.co/RDPWWGX

Comment: The small description has two lines of text, pushing the rating to the bottom... see edited answer, I think that's the best way.

Comment: I added an if/else statement : "If I have free shipping display free-shipping text, else display an empty div with  height: 18px"

And it worked ! Thank you, your code was great !

Answer (score 0):

What I finally did :

I used the code from @Giu Magnani and I added an if/else statement :

If free-shipping display free shipping text
Else display empty div with height = 18px;

And it worked exactly like I wanted !
Thanks to everyone who helped me and have a nice day ! :)